# DataDog agent cannot find JAR process with matching name

Tags: jar, datadog, process-monitoring

I have configured DD agent on AWS Ubuntu machine and defined CPU Usage, RAM monitors, and metric is correctly reflecting in the dashboard.

Inside `/etc/dd-agent/conf.d` in file `process.yaml`:

```
init_config:

instances:
  - name: ecommerce-order
    search_string: ['ecommerce-order']
    tags:
      - env:dev
```

On the same machine, I have a JAR running as a process with name `ecommerce-order-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` as a process.

When I do:

```
ps -ef | grep ecommerce-order
```

I get:

```
root  350  1  0 Oct12 ?  00:13:29 java -Xmx100m -Xms50m -XX:+UseG1GC 
  -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=45 -jar 
  -Dspring.profiles.active=dev ./ecommerce-order-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But when I do:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/datadog-agent info
```

I get:

```
Checks
======
process (5.18.0)
----------------
  - instance #0 [WARNING]
      Warning: No matching process 'ecommerce-order' was found
  - Collected 1 metric, 0 events & 1 service check
```

I want a process monitor who can check if a `JAR` with some name is currently running or not. What is it I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is to add the ["exact_match: false"](https://github.com/DataDog/integrations-core/blob/5.18.x/process/conf.yaml.example#L21-L22) option, like so:

```
init_config:

instances:
  - name: ecommerce-order
    search_string: ['ecommerce-order']
    exact_match: False
    tags:
      - env:dev
```

This should match on any process whose path+name *include* the search string you provide.

Alternatively, if you only want it to match on the name of the process, you'll want to set the search_string to be the exact name of the process that's running (so whatever is given as the name when you run a `ps | grep "ecommerce-order"`, which in your case seems to be `ecommerce-order-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`)